# Can you compare two ember objects?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am pulling a number of objects in from my database as searchResult objects (a model that I have defined and set up).

Now I need to put these objects in a JS array - if they are not already in them. JS arrays have a "if --- in array" but it does not truly compare custom objects. The simplest solution is to use a double loop and check each incoming object with each already existing object in the array, but my searchResult objects have several properties that I simply cannot spend time comparing.

So is there a way to check, for example, if (searchResult1 == searchResult2) in Ember itself?

I know there is a comparable mixing, but I am unsure if that will help - or even how to use it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ember provides a helpful method, `addObject`, to Array prototypes to solve this sort of problem. `arr.addObject(item)` will inject `item` into `arr` if the item is not already there.

http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.MutableArray.html#method_addObject :

```
var cities = ["Chicago", "Berlin"];
cities.addObject("Lima");    // ["Chicago", "Berlin", "Lima"]
cities.addObject("Berlin");  // ["Chicago", "Berlin", "Lima"]
```

There's also `addObjects`, which accepts an array of items and adds each one that isn't already present: `arr.addObjects([itemA, itemB, itemC])`.

**EDIT:** as GJK rightly notes, this is implemented with `===`, so for complex objects this compares references rather than values. As such, this will work fine if you are adding Ember Models, or if you're adding Primatives, but will fail if you're simply comparing Objects.

Same goes for standard Javascript (`[1] === [1] // => false`, but `var i = [1]; i === i // => true`)

Comment: It should be noted that this only compares references. So the objects must be equal using `===`. (They might use the internal GUID, but it would be the same.) If you want a deep comparison, you'll have to use the Comparable mixin.

Comment: @GJK AFAIK, it doesn't work on Ember models either:
https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/e04415c31a677ac918864decced8a4c9a887cbe1/packages_es6/ember-runtime/lib/mixins/enumerable.js#L193